# setInterval with Infinity

Tags: javascript

So If i am doing:

```
setInterval(function(){

   console.log("1");

},Infinity);
```

It keeps on logging `1` as if it is a `for loop`. Why is that behaviour?

Comment: 1) Because `setInterval` essentially *is* a `for` loop. 2) Because the comparison to determine whether it's time for the next iteration likely arrives at the answer *yes* at any time using a comparison to `Infinity`. – Since this code is rather nonsensical, I wouldn't expect any particular "right" answer here anyway.

Comment: @deceze What I think is the output is nonsensical.

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out. :)

Comment: @deceze hehe yeah, right!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the float/number `Infinity` needs to be converted to a 32-bit integer value in JavaScript, as it does for setTimeout, it's converted to zero:

```
console.log(typeof Infinity); // number
console.log(Infinity | 0);    // 0
```

> ### [ECMA-262 6e Section 7.1.5 `ToInt32 ( argument )`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toint32)
>
> The abstract operation `ToInt32` converts `argument` to one of 2<sup>32</sup> integer
>   values in the range −2<sup>31</sup> through 2<sup>31</sup>−1, inclusive. This abstract
>   operation functions as follows:
>
> 1. Let number be `ToNumber(argument)`.
> 2. `ReturnIfAbrupt(number)`.
> 3. **If number is NaN, +0, −0, +∞, or −∞, return +0.**
> 4. [...]

Answer (score 3):

`Infinity` only has use in arithmetics, and its behaviour is therefore only defined in arithmetics. In any other context it's just [an object with some properties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-value-properties-of-the-global-object-infinity):

> The value of Infinity is +∞ (see 6.1.6). This property has the
>   attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false,
>   [[Configurable]]: false }.

As this object has no use as the `delay` parameter of `setTimeout` that function executes as if no object was supplied, so `0`.

Comment: Nit: It's not an object, those aren't its properties. It's a primitive number/float and that's the configuration of the property providing it on the global object.

Comment: @JeremyBanks thanks for the addition, I meant specifically that that is how the type is perceived outside arithmetic context. Your explanation is better and more complete anyway for this specific question so you have my vote :)

Answer (score 1):

My closest guess is that the interval argument you specify in `setInterval` is subjected to division when compared with the time counters to determine if the next iteration should be done. The function must be called without an interval since it is zero when any number is divided by Infinity.

```
if (counter / Infinity === 0)
   callback();
```

In the above code, `callback()` will execute for any counter.